# convert date to end of day , excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

the below code keep adding 23:59HRS to the date and i need to run the code 4 - 5 times a day and it will add till it changes the initial date. i just want to make it till the end of the day for that date without adding it.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim test1 As Date
Dim schdWS, compWS As Worksheet
Const H23M59 As Double = 1 - 60 / 86400

Set schdWS = Sheet1
Set compWS = Sheet11

     lastrow = schdWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 20 To lastrow

                If IsDate(schdWS.Cells(x, 3).Value) Then
                       Cells(x, 3).Value = CDate(Int(Cells(x, 3).Value + H23M59))
                End If
Next x

End sub
```

Comment: Can not understand what you want. Your code is clear: if column C is a date, add the constant (almost 1 day). What do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example my column c date is 12/June 00:00 by running the code once it will be 12/June 23:59hrs , if I run again it will be 13/June 23:58hrs. I need the code to identify the date and running the macro for 4-5 times it will be still be 12/June 23:59hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `If` inside the loop with the following

```
If IsDate(schdWS.Cells(x, 3).Value) Then
    'Get rid of hours, min and secs
    TheDay = Int(schdWS.Cells(x, 3).Value)
    TheEndOfDay = TheDay + H23M59
    'I write the result in col4 for clarity. Replace according to your needs.
    schdWS.Cells(x, 4).Value = Format(TheEndOfDay, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS")
End If
```